# Creating object in typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

I am new to ionic3 and angular5
I have following code

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  constructor() {
   console.log("I am in constructor")
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {
  currentUser: User;
  currentUser1 = new User()
}
```

What is difference between

```
1.currentUser: User 
2.currentUser1 = new User()
```

If I use `currentUser : User` will it call default constructor?

Comment: Where is `currentUser = new User()` line of code? it should throw an error.. First is just a declaration and second is initialization

Comment: @SurajRao it is not showing any error.this code in AuthProvider class at second line.Check edited one now!

Comment: First line doesnt create an object.. its a reference declared of type User. Second is creating an object of type User and assigning to currentUser1

Answer (score 1):

1. Following statement will create a reference `currentUser` and set type of it as `User`. It will not create any object.

> let currentUser: User;

2. Following statement will create object `currentUser1` using `User` class.

> let currentUser1 = new User();

Answer (score 0):

> currentUser: User;

Its a reference declared of type User

> currentUser1 = new User()

Its create an object of type User and its assigning to currentUser1